# Resizing cloud VM disk without taking instance down (Google cloud)

Tags: google-compute-engine, nfs, disk

So I saw there is an option in google compute (I assume the same option exists in other cloud VM suppliers so the question isnt specifically on Google compute, but on the underlying technology) to resize the disk without having to restart the machine, and I ask, how is this possible?

Even if it uses some sort of abstraction to the disk and they dont actually assign a physical disk to the VM, but just part of the disk (or part of a number of disks), once the disk is created in the guest VM is has a certain size, how can it change without needing a restart? Does it utilize NFS somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is built directly into disk protocols these days. This capability has existed for a while, since disks have been virtualized since the late 1990s (either through network protocols like iSCSI / FibreChannel, or through a software-emulated version of hardware like VMware).

Like the VMware model, GCE doesn't require any additional network hops or protocols to do this; the hypervisor just exposes the virtual disk as if it is a physical device, and the guest knows that its size can change and handles that. GCE uses a virtualization-specific driver type for its disks called VirtIO SCSI, but this feature is implemented in many other driver types (across many OSes) as well.

---

Since a disk can be resized at any time, disk protocols need a way to tell the guest that an update has occurred. In general terms, this works as follows in most protocols:

- Administrator resizes disk from hypervisor UI (or whatever storage virtualization UI they're using).
- Nothing happens inside the guest until it issues an IO to the disk.
- Guest OS issues an IO command to the disk, via the device driver in the guest OS.
- Hypervisor emulates that IO command, notices that the disk has been resized and the guest hasn't been alerted yet, and returns a response to the guest telling it to update its view of the device.
- The guest OS recognizes this response and re-queries the device size and other details via some other command.

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the reason it's structured like this is that traditionally disks cannot send updates to the OS unless the OS requests them first. This is probably because the disk has no way to know what memory is free to write to, and even if it did, no way to synchronize access to that memory with the OS. However, those constraints are becoming less true to enable ultra-high-throughput / ultra-low-latency SSDs and NVRAM, so new disk protocols such as NVMe may do this slightly differently (I don't know).